# Sufficient condition for $L^\infty$ distance bound

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Suppose for two functions $f, g\in L^{\infty}([0,1])$ and $$||f-g||_{L_1([0,1])}\leq \epsilon$$ Under what condition can we get $||f-g||_{L^\infty([0,1])}\leq K(\epsilon)$ where $K(\cdot)$ is some function (e.g., logarithm function)? What is the weakest condition to ensure $K(\epsilon)=\tilde{K}\cdot\epsilon$ for some constant $\tilde{K}$?

Comment: We can add conditions like $f,g$ satisfy certain regularity conditions, I just want to figure out what could be the weakest condition we need to impose.

Comment: For convenience I'll set $g = 0$ (this doesn't matter at all for what I'm going to say next). The prototypical example of a function with small $L_1$ but large $L_\infty$ norm is a very tall function on a very narrow area. To exclude these, you'd like to control how much $f$ can grow in a short interval. One common condition for this is [Hoelder continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition), which leads to a bound of $O(C^{1/\alpha} \epsilon^{ \alpha/(\alpha + 1)} )$. Note that these conditions imply uniform continuity, so may be too strong for your taste.